# Labeling same dates in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe with dates:

df:

```
date     value
20210403 1 
20210403 33
20210401 33
20210408 44
20210401 -11 
20210402 333
```

I want to label the same dates and get the output:

```
date     value  date_label
20210403 1               1
20210403 33              1
20210401 33              2
20210408 44              3
20210401 -11             2 
20210402 333             4
```

I thought about taking `df.date.unique()` and adding a column of labels and then `rejoin` it to my df.
Is there any built in function to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution you can try out, `enumerate` on the unique date values and `map` it back to original df.

```
map_ = {j: i for i, j in enumerate(df['date'].unique(), 1)}

df['date_label'] = df['date'].map(map_)
```

---

```
       date  value  date_label
0  20210403      1           1
1  20210403     33           1
2  20210401     33           2
3  20210408     44           3
4  20210401    -11           2
5  20210402    333           4
```

Comment: Did something similar but with merge (inner join with unique dates and their ids on the right and original df on the left).